# plotting whit subplots in a loop python

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a loop to subplot timelines for different series in a data frame.
I tried this:

m: is a vector whit the columns of the data frame that I want to depict

```
c=0
  i=0
   for x in m:
      fig, axs = plt.subplots(6, 6)
      axs[c,i].plot( x )
    i=i+1
c=c+1
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Do you have any ideas?

Thx